# Is this a house sparrow fledgling? (Found a bird in my garage)

Tags: united-states, birds

I left my garage door open for about an hour last night on a windy day, and I later heard incessant chirping inside Apparently, this fledgling somehow go into, and was trapped, in an old bag over 18 inches high. I wrapped him in a hand-towel put him in a small dish inside a shoebox for the night, & he fell asleep. I plan on releasing him this morning, but I'm concerned that this may be a house sparrow? There are mourning doves that have nested right above my garage for about 4 years now. I caught house sparrows about 2 years ago on video destroying their nest and dropping eggs. Would you please help me identify this fledgling? Is it a house sparrow, a mourning dove, or something else? And what is the best course of action for releasing him in the yard? (This is in South Carolina)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot help you identify the bird, but I can tell you that you can't just release it in your yard. Well, not if you want it to survive...

Comment: doesnt look like sparrow, they get distinctive feathers on wings early

Comment: true, it is a little big for a sparrow fledging

Comment: I think this question belongs to biology SE. They have [species-identification] tag.